# Reusing a python filehandler?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new to python and I 
need a help to understand the codes below -

```
def main():
    print('main')

    fh = open('C:\\Python\\lines.txt')
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line, end = '')

    fh = open('C:\\Python\\lines.txt')
    for index,line in enumerate(fh.readlines()):
        print(index, line, end = '')

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

When I remove the second fh = open..., then
the second for loop does not print. Why ?

Comment: `fh.seek(0)`?  You need to reset the handle's internal position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read through a [primer or a tutorial on the best practices with dealing with file handlers](http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html).  As you did not close the first instance of `fh`, in larger programs you will run into issues where the system kernel will fail your program for having too many open file handles, which is definitely a bad thing.  In traditional languages you have to do a lot more dancing, but in python you can just use the context manager:

```
with open('C:\\Python\\lines.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line, end = '')
```

Naturally, the file position is something that is changed whenever the file is read, and that will put the position towards the end, so if you want to do this

```
with open('C:\\Python\\lines.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line, end = '')

    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(index, line, end = '')
```

The second set of read will not be able to read anything unless you do `fh.seek(0)` in between the two for loops.

Comment: yes, and `fh.close()` must be put when fh is not used any longer.

Comment: Not if you use `with`, as the file handler context manager will handle the closing for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your file handle contains a position pointer.  You can find out where you're at using `fh.tell`.  It will move through the file for each line.  Once you reach the end of the line, if you want to iterate through it again, you need to reset this pointer.  `fh.seek(0)` would accomplish that for you.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the API/Docs for this ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Comment: Thanks. The python apis look cluttered and ugly. Java is so much cleaner. Anyway, I'll live with that.